# How to merge, join, concatenate the first two columns in a text file separated by underscore?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text: SG_gen.txt file with multiple columns looking like this:

```
  snp_CHR      POS HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
   snp_3 47609552       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47614413       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47616151       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47616155       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47617504       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47617679       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
...
```

I would like to join the first two columns: snp_CHR and POS by "_" and rename it to ID so that column would look like this:

```
ID
snp_3_47609552
snp_3_47614413
snp_3_47616151
...
```

This new ID column would be the first column and I would keep all those other columns HG00096, HG00097...I would not keep the original snp_CHR and POS. How would I do this?

I tried using:

```
awk '{print $0, $1 "_" $NF}' SG_gen.txt > SG_gen1.txt
```

but this didn't gave me my desired result.

Comment: Are there really leading spaces in SG_gen.txt?

Comment: `awk '{print $1 "_" $2}' `

Comment: this removed all of my other columns: HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100...and created just one column, the column I need but I also need all of these others: HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100...

Comment: That's **extremely** lucky that you got the best possible answer to your question within 20 minutes of asking it. Or did you...? Guess we'll never know since you accepted an answer already which discourages anyone else from posting answers.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this. I checked the solution and it worked. Can you please explain what would be the criterium to accept the answer aside that it works for this purpose? Also my question is very basic I think

Comment: By "works" I assume you mean produces the posted expected output from the posted sample input. That is the starting point for a program. After that you need to think about robustness (will it work for other input), clarity, simplicity, portability, efficiency, maintainability, enhancability, and all of the other criteria that matter in software. if the only thing you care about is getting the posted expected output from the posted sample input then you might miss an opportunity to get a solution that is better in some of the many possible ways it could be.

Comment: this solution makes sense to me, it is readable and I know how to interpret it. It is also coherent and simple. In my opinion.

Comment: Right and you have nothing else to compare it to so you're happy. Understood. I'm just advising you that that's not a great approach in general, but as long as you're happy with your results then that's great.

Comment: but I will take as a note for future to wait and see what other answers are there. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do:

```
awk '{$1=(NR==1?"ID":$1"_"$2); $2=""}1' file
```

there will be extra white space, which can be normalized afterwards if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try Perl. Note that this retains the spaces between other columns as in your sample input.

```
$ cat anika.txt
 snp_CHR      POS HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
   snp_3 47609552       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47614413       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47616151       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47616155       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47617504       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
   snp_3 47617679       0       1       1       1       1       0       1

$ perl -pe 's/^\s*//g;  s/\s/_/; s/^\S+\s+\S+/ID/ if $.==1' anika.txt
ID HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102 HG00103
snp_3_47609552       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
snp_3_47614413       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
snp_3_47616151       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
snp_3_47616155       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
snp_3_47617504       0       1       1       1       1       0       1
snp_3_47617679       0       1       1       1       1       0       1

$
```